# Raspbian Desktop shortcut doesn't launch tkinter GUI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have Developed a tkinter GUI which is used to take an input of 2 fields and when I compile it within the Terminal using "python3 GuiTest.py" the GUI works, I have turned the file into a executable using "chmod +x" which when clicking on it within the file manager also works with the popup window of what would you like to do "execute, execute in terminal, open or cancel".

GUI ran from either Terminal or executable file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHZlo.png)

Yet when I attempt to create a shortcut for the executable on the desktop, the file briefly opens a grey window which closes quickly after opening. The contents of the shortcut are as followed, note that I have attempted it with the standard .py file before I used "chmod +x" to turn it into an executable.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Altimex
Comment=Altimex
Icon=/home/pi/Exec/AltimexIcon.ico
Exec=/home/pi/Exec/AltimexLogin
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

I am using tkinter for python3 and have the shebang at the top of my python file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

I have only been using Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi and python for few days so please explain the process of correcting the issue I have so that I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: As your screenshot shows a background image in the GUI: Is your Python program independent of the current working directory?  I.e. does it find data files like the image file regardless what the current working directory is?

Comment: The is background image is packaged together with the program therefore file path shouldn't be an issue as far as im aware, since the directory which contains exectutable should become root level.

Comment: The directory which contains the programs is not necessarily the current working directory.  Most likely that is either the home directory or the directory where the *.desktop file is saved, depending on the desktop environment and how exactly the program is started. Loading resources should be independent from the current working directory. So use the `__file__` attribute of the main module of your program and `os.path.dirname()` and then `os.path.join()` to build paths relative to that module to load resources from.

Comment: Thanks for your help, while i wasn't able to wrap my head around the method which you suggested it did enable me to rethink my issue logically and discovered that i just missed a line of text in my .desktop file.

All which was required was to set the working directory using:
Path=/home/pi/Altimex/